# os.execute variables

Tags: variables, lua, operating-system

I have multiple Steam accounts that I want to launch via a single Lua script with the options I specify. I've got pretty much everything sorted, except for launching with the code provided. I have no idea how to "pass" the variable with this format.

```
function Steam(n, opt1, opt2, opt3)
os.execute[["start C:\Program" "Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe /box:Steam2 D:\Steam\steam.exe -login username password -opt1 -opt2 -opt3"]]
end
```

I have my usernames and Sandboxes setup so that only the number needs changing (fenriros2, fenriros3, Steam2, Steam3 etc) with the same password.

Basically, I want this;

```
Steam(3, -tf, -exit, -textmode)
```

to do;

```
os.execute[["start C:\Program" "Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe /box:Steam3 D:\Steam\steam.exe -login fenriros3 password -applaunch 440 -textmode"]]
```

I'll use -exit to close the lua window after it's done.

I realize my code isn't exactly efficient, but that's a worry for a later time. Right now I just need to get it working.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I apologize if I missed something obvious, I'm still fairly new at Lua.

Comment: Are you really asking how to put a string together in Lua? Or how to convert an integer to a string?

Comment: I'm asking how I can put a variable in os.execute with my configuration. If that isn't allowed, let me know and I'll delete this.

Comment: `os.execute` takes a *string*. Therefore, you're asking how to take a string and stick the values of one or more variables into that string in a certain location.

Comment: I see. I knew it was something stupid. Apologies for taking your time, and thank you for the reply. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First obvious one.    The [[  ]]  delimit a string so all you need to do is to create a variable for the string and replace the contents as needed.

```
function Steam(n, opt1, opt2, opt3)
-- Set up execute string with placeholders for the parameters.
local strExecute = [["start C:\Program" "Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe /box:Steam{n} D:\Steam\steam.exe -login fenriros{n} password -{opt1} -{opt2} -{opt3}"]]

-- Use gsub to replace the parameters
-- You could just concat the string but I find it easier to work this way.
strExecute = strExecute:gsub('{n}',n)
strExecute = strExecute:gsub('{opt1}',opt1:gsub('%%','%%%%'))
strExecute = strExecute:gsub('{opt2}',opt2:gsub('%%','%%%%'))
strExecute = strExecute:gsub('{opt3}',opt3:gsub('%%','%%%%'))
os.execute(strExecute)
end

Steam(1,'r1','r2','r3')
```

Comment: Thank you and apologies for wasting your time with this. I somehow knew I was stumbling on something stupid. In any case, I greatly appreciate your reply!